# Sync Framework not Provisiong Sql Compact when number of primary keys are different

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce, microsoft-sync-framework

I am trying to sync Sql Compact With Sql Server. Every thing works fine if number of primary keys are similar in client and server table. But If number of primary keys are not same in both tables I Get the following Exception

**The given key was not present in the dictionary.**

**Stack Trace:**

*at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException()
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeSyncUtil.GetPkInOrdinalOrder(IEnumerable`1 pkColumns, Dictionary`2 pkIndexOrder)
   at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeSyncTableProvisioning.Apply(SqlCeTransaction trans)
   at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeSyncScopeProvisioning.ApplyInternal(SqlCeConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeSyncScopeProvisioning.Apply()
   at SQLCompactDeployment.Program.ProvisionClient(String ServerConnectionString, String ClientConnectionString, Boolean IsSqlServerCompact) in M:\Windows 2020\Documents\repos\SQLCompactDeployment\SQLCompactDeployment\Program.cs:line 296*

**Table Structure in Server**

```
USE [Server]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Customer]    Script Date: 3/26/2020 6:09:31 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [TenantId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Customer_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC,
    [TenantId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

**Table Structure In Client**

```
USE [Client]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Customer]    Script Date: 3/26/2020 6:09:20 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [TenantId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Customer_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

**Syncing Code**

```
public static bool ProvisionServer(string ServerConnectionString)
{
    try
    {
        string scopeName = "SyncScope";
        SqlConnection serverConn = new SqlConnection(ServerConnectionString);
        DbSyncScopeDescription SyncScope = new DbSyncScopeDescription(scopeName);
        DbSyncTableDescription Customer = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable("Customer", serverConn);
        SyncScope.Tables.Add(Customer);
        SqlSyncScopeProvisioning serverProvision = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(serverConn, SyncScope);
        serverProvision.SetCreateTableDefault(DbSyncCreationOption.Skip);
        serverProvision.Apply();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public static bool ProvisionClient(string ServerConnectionString, string ClientConnectionString, bool IsSqlServerCompact)
{
    try
    {
        string scopeName = "SyncScope";
        SqlConnection serverConn = new SqlConnection(ServerConnectionString);
        DbSyncScopeDescription scopeDesc = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForScope(scopeName, serverConn);
        if (IsSqlServerCompact)
        {
            SqlCeConnection clientConnCe = new SqlCeConnection(ClientConnectionString);
            SqlCeSyncScopeProvisioning clientProvision = new SqlCeSyncScopeProvisioning(clientConnCe, scopeDesc);
            clientProvision.Apply();
        }
        else
        {
            SqlConnection clientConn = clientConn = new SqlConnection(ClientConnectionString);
            SqlSyncScopeProvisioning clientProvision = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(clientConn, scopeDesc);
            clientProvision.Apply();
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

*With the same structure If I sync From Sql server database to Sql server database it Works.*

Comment: Have a look oh this framework : https://github.com/mimetis/Dotmim.Sync/ 
if you are not required to use SQL CE on the client side

Comment: I am required to use SQL CE on client side or SQL lite.

Comment: So you should give it a try 

Comment: @SébastienPertus Does it work for SQL CE and SQL Server. SQL Server is server and SQL Server CE is client in my case

Comment: nop. Client can be SQLite, SQL Server or MySQL. SQL CE is not supported

Comment: @SébastienPertus How can we initialize and upload already inserted data? https://dotmimsync.readthedocs.io/AlreadyExisting.html#solution. This example is not working

Comment: depends if it's data already exting in server or client ?
can you please open an issue on the github repo ?

Comment: its in client and I need it to upload to server. The example in your page goes something like this (conf =>{
    conf.Add(new string[] { "ServiceTickets" }). conf.Add is not a function

Comment: You have a undocumented (yet) method to do that.
See here https://github.com/Mimetis/Dotmim.Sync/issues/279#issuecomment-633255163